# How to set different session names for different routes in Silex?

Tags: php, session, symfony, routes, silex

I have Silex app based on
https://github.com/silexphp/Silex-Skeleton
with two controller providers:

```
$app->mount('/admin/', new Kw5\Provider\AdminControllerProvider());
$app->mount('/', new Kw5\Provider\SiteControllerProvider());
```

Every mount point has one route:

```
$controllers->match('/{url}', 'Kw5\\Controller\[Admin|Site]Controller::index'
```

I need two session names for that mount points and need login to

```
/admin/
```

How to correctly set session names?

Comment: why do you need 2 seperate session names ?

Comment: to completely separate session vars